# Highlight text In TextView which might contains HTML tags

Tags: java, android, regex, textview, highlight

I want to make an application about regex. User input a regex and a test text, and I want to highlight everything in the test text that matches the regex. Now I've made something like this:

```
// txaTestText is an EditText
Editable testText = txaTestText.getText(); 

// pattern is a java.util.regex.Pattern input by user
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(testText);

// txaFindResult is a TextView
txaFindResult.setText(Html.fromHtml(matcher
        .replaceAll("<font color=\"red\">$0</font>")));
```

The issue is user may input some string including HTML tags as the test text. For example:

- regex = `o`
- test text = `Hello<br>world`
- expected result = `Hello<br>world` <sub>(Since StackOverflow don't support coloring, I use bold here instead)</sub>
- real result = `Hello
  world`

I tried to use `Html.escapeHtml`. However it is added in API level 16, while my minimum require is 8.

**My question is how to solve the issue above?**

Comment: You may try replace `<` with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;`.

Comment: If the regex is `<` and test text is `&lt; <`, it will go wrong.

Comment: I'm talking about the result, so you should replace that in the result, not the input.

Comment: Do you mean `txaFindResult.setText(Html.fromHtml(matcher.replaceAll("<font color=\"red\">$0</font>").replace("<", "&lt;").replace(">", "&gt;")))`? Or what?

Comment: Sorry but I don't code in Java. This was just an idea that I got from a function in PHP [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars).

Comment: I meant that replacing those in the result also changes my actual HTML tags and finally result in showing `<font color="red">o</font>`

Comment: If you can sacrifice the `<font>` tag, you maybe could use a [regex](http://regex101.com/r/iO9nY9) to replace `<>`

Comment: Sorry that I disconnected for an hour, but I don't want to sacrifice correctness. I suppose there must be some way to approach, possibly without HTMLs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [Spans](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/package-summary.html):

Spannables can be used to alternate parts of the TextView's text: e.g. color with [ForeGroundColorSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ForegroundColorSpan.html). It can even be used to introduce an image inline with the text (emoticons in a textmessage).

here is a hard coded example highlighting the `<br>` part. you should add the regex algorithme:

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.helloworld);
        Spannable spannableString = new SpannableString(getString(R.string.hello_world));        
        spannableString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 5, 10, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        textView.setText(spannableString);

    }
```

**strings.xml**

```
<string name="hello_world">
  <![CDATA[
    Hello <br> World 
  ]]>
</string>
```

**main.xml**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/helloworld"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

[image: Screenshot highlight <br> tag]